# Powershell making folders and adding files

Tags: powershell

I have a poweshell file that makes a folder gives it the name of a chosen year then makes 12 folders inside it and labels them 01 April to 12 March.

Something I would like to add is the main folder shows the year (this is from a user input) is the folder to display the year and plus 1 year as the contents of the folder spans 2 years ie:  2021 - 2022. I hope I have explained that OK.

New addition, every one of the 12 folders contains the same file is there a way of placing that file in the folder when or just after they are created, the file lives in the same master folder as the powershell script, basically everything happens within the master folder.

Here is what there is so far:

```pwsh
###Get the year entered by the user
$year = Read-Host "Please enter year"

###Set the starting date
$startdate = [DateTime] "01 April $($year)"
$count = 1

###Create folder based on the year entered by the user
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$($year)"

###Change directory to the newly created folder
cd "$($year)"

While ( $count -lt 13)
{
###Create folders 
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$($count.ToString('00')) - $($startdate.ToString('MMMM yyyy'))"

#Add one month
$startdate = $startdate.AddMonths(1)

#Increment the counter
$count = $count + 1

}
```

Comment: You want the main older to display let say `2024-2025` instead of `2024`?

Comment: Yes  the user enters the year 2024 and that is used to name the folder.  I would like it to name it 2024 - 2025. So whatever year is entered the second part is + 1 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code to include both years when creating the folder. Plus copying the file (in this case `a.txt`) to all 12 folders after creating them. You need to change `a.txt` to the correct filename.

```ps
###Get the year entered by the user
$year = Read-Host "Please enter year"

$nextyear = [int]$year + 1

$yearfolder = "$year-$nextyear"

###Set the starting date
$startdate = [DateTime] "01 April $($year)"
$count = 1

###Set the file's path by combining the folder path and the filename
$filename = join-Path -Path (Get-location) -ChildPath "a.txt"

###Create folder based on the year entered by the user
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$($yearfolder)"

###Change directory to the newly created folder
cd "$($yearfolder)"


While ( $count -lt 13)
{
###Create folders 
$newfolder = "$($count.ToString('00')) - $($startdate.ToString('MMMM yyyy'))"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "$newfolder"

#Copy file to new folder
Copy-Item -Path $filename -Destination $newfolder

#Add one month
$startdate = $startdate.AddMonths(1)

#Increment the counter
$count = $count + 1

}
```

Comment: So if the file to be attached to th 12 folders was a excel with macro. It would be filename.xlsm

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a text file nor an excel macro file. You need to set the correct filename. For example, `something.xlsm`.

Comment: Is Alan saying it needs to be a little more dynamic using `$_.Name` perhaps getting it from a `Get-ChildItem` so it can just process whatever the source files are right over to the destination location without the `$filename` needing to be set each time run for the "Copy" portion of this question? I think that's what Alan is talking about perhaps but maybe not.

Comment: I was more doting the I and crossing the T really. My knowledge of powershell is non existent,  Reddy has been very helpful and has proved a solution based on what I have asked, I appreciate any and all assistance that is offered but when you mention $_.Name, Get-ChildItem, etc with my very limited knowledge  I struggle to understand, that said many thanks for your input.

Comment: All good, that's how we learn—try things, ask questions, get clarity, and ah ha!! { : - ) ... Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you resolve!

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` is the powershell equivalent to `dir` command. What @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle is saying there is possibility of avoiding hard coding the filename directly into the code and use `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve it dynamically especially if the name changes depending on the folder(s).

Comment: That sounds like a good option then the file will upload regardless.

Comment: +1 from me on this earlier, not sure why someone downvoted without comment. The requestor stated this answered the questions asked. If I downvoted, I'd at least leave a comment to give the question or answerer a chance to correct whatever issue there is.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle The very first answer I gave on this site was down-voted with no comment although it was correct. Unfortunately, few are those who mention the reasons why they down-vote.

Comment: Down-voting. Is this something I have done by mistake, If so please let me know and how to correct.

Comment: @Alan-53 We "normal users" don't have the means to know who down-voted an answer or questions unless the person who did states it. When you upvote or downvote, the arrow will change color from grey to blue (upvote) or orange (downvote). Take a [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) of the site.